# Mongoid relational attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

What is the best way for saving relational attributes? For example, I have models Person and Project (M:N relation). I want to save persons role in project. In relational database it will be an attribute in junction table person_project. What is the best way to implemnt this in Mongoid (RoR)?

And second question: Should I save ids for many to many relation on both or just one side?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :persons
end
```

Mongoid uses Arrays to store IDs in both the collections. `Person` collection has a field `project_ids` and `Project` collection has a field `person_ids`

Comment: Please, read carefully. I didnt ask how to build M:N relation, but where to save "role" attribute for this relation.

Answer (score 0):

I wont store user or specific user roles in project, (except superuser, or for eventual caching reasons). Just because there are two life cycles and you probably wont mess around with users when you are doing project stuff.
So as a start I would store the role settings in persons like so:

```
{
 _id : Obj{},
 projects : [
   {project_one : role_name}, //use a name if name is unique if not use project_id as key
   {project_two : role_name}
 ]
}
```

or maybe easier but needs more space

```
{
_id : Obj{},
projects : [
  {project_id : project_one,
   role : role_name},...
]
}
```

Even if you may store some user related stuff in projects, i would always test roles against users.